# How to ssh tunnel to ec2 for running a local python script

Tags: ssh, python, amazon-ec2, tunnel

I can create a tunnel for FF using the below on Ubuntu.  Machine is 12.04 in a VBox on a mac host.

```
 -i ~/.ec2/aws_development_oregon.pem -C2qTnN -D 8080 ubuntu@test.com
```

But..what I need is for my my python scripts to tunnel though.  How do I have all traffic on the Vbox tunnel though the ec2 instance or at least have the python 2.7 script use the tunnel?

I looked into sshuttle but I dont understand how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: I have deleted the VirtualBox tag as I don't feel VB makes any difference here. If you disagree feel free to add it back.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem, but have you looked [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell)? I've used Fabric before to execute code on a remote machine.